# page loads with Random character instead of normal html

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, apc

I have apc enabled. Nginx used as "reverse proxy". At some point, let's say after a few hours, the page suddenly loads some random non-understandable characters.

I checked the error log for both apache and nginx, nothing abnormal. What could be the problem? If you need some furder info please do ask.

Comment: Can it be related to gzip-compression? I encountered a similar problem with unarchived data. So it can be the cause, if your nginx compresses output data.

Comment: where is the random character appear?

Comment: on every page @SergeiLomakov just complete random non-`[a-zA-Z]` characters.

Comment: could you disable Apc and test again?

Comment: I tried clearing the opcode cache and nginx cache and it fixed the problem, but I'm wondering what could be causing the problem. Could it really be gzip?